# ClassNotFoundException in scala-xml with Scala 2.13

Tags: xml, scala, scala-xml

I have been using scala-xml successfully for a long time on Linux. I recently upgraded to Scala `2.13.0` and `scala-xml 1.2.0`. I am using `sbt 1.2.8` with this line:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-xml" % "1.2.0"
```

It compiles, but then I get a runtime error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.xml.MetaData
```

Any idea what the problem could be? Thanks.

Comment: also asked at https://users.scala-lang.org/t/scala-collection-seqops-not-found/4984

Answer (score 0):

With some kind help from the Scala user forum, I figured out that this problem was the result of an inconsistent CLASSPATH at run time vs. compile time.